# Android: App does not appear in drawer when mimeType is set

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I have an Activity that is both the MainActivity and the activity that should be started when the 'Share'-Button within the Gallery is clicked.

So my Manifest looks like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

With the above manifest, by app appears within the share menu but not in the app drawer. If I remove the line that sets the mimeType the app appears in the app drawer but not within the share menu in the gallery.

Any suggestions how to achieve both?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two separate `<intent-filter>` elements in the `<activity>`: one for `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER`, the other for `SEND`/`DEFAULT`/MIME type.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```